# Fill section between two circles ipe7

Tags: technical-drawing, ipe

I don't know if anyone here is skilled with Ipe7. A drawing tool for LaTeX.

I have two circles. One with a radius of X the other with radius X + Y, a wheel. Now I want the area between those circles filled with a color. How do I do this?

I tried joining the two circles but that fails saying: `a selected object does not consists of open curves`.

I also tried filling one circle and making the other opaque.

Anyone knows how to do this?

---

Edit: I fixed it currently by creation 2 arcs and connecting them together. However now I have a again a shape which can't be propperly joined... Hopefully someone can help me with this and explain how it is done good...

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20782274/test2.ipe

Comment: If you enable object snapping you can draw CW or CCW arcs by snapping to each circle and drawing the intersecting arc. Then right click on the curve and select `stroke&fill -> Fill only`.

Comment: @percusse This was an answer, not a comment?

Comment: @Sveinung It's just a description I need to get the screenshots etc. to write a proper answer.

Comment: @percusse I didn't really understand what you meant but I did now the following. I just build two arcs and connected them together.

Answer (score 7):

To be able to draw complicated shapes you need to draw the sub paths individually and then connect them by selecting two subpaths and then by right clicking on any of them selecting the `Join Paths` option. That will apply the line join settings on the subpaths and end points are joined properly.

In your example your subpath endpoints are not exactly aligned hence they cannot be joined.

[image]

The easiest way to do this without such problems is to use the endpoint snapping and starting next subpath from the snapped position. If I redraw the upper part of the problematic curve by guessing and joining all the paths I obtain the following

[image]

Comment: What is `endpoint snapping`? I assume you mean `vertex snapping`? And "In your example your subpath endpoints are not exactly aligned hence they cannot be joined." Why not? I used vertex snapping and moved the endpoint of the line exactly to the end of the other...

Comment: @WG- I wish I knew why it didn't work but fixing it solves the issue as you can see from the screenshot.

Comment: Isn't there a way to draw a path and then divide it to several sub-paths. I mean something like splitting a curve at prescribed points. Or maybe even intersecting two curves such that the intersection points are identified.

Answer (score 3):

A common ipe drawing technique is rather than drawing something directly, draw a background and then subtract from it. In your case, that would mean fill the larger circle with the color, and then fill the smaller circle with white. Bring the smaller circle to the front so that it is drawn on top of the larger circle. In the drawing below, the circles don't have the same center, since I couldn't tell from your question if that's what you wanted or not. You can draw much more complicated shapes this way as well, without having to deal with joining paths.

[image: circle-in-circle]

Comment: Can you also apply it to the given example? I don't think subtraction is an easier alternative to that shape.

Comment: @percusse for the shape in your answer, I agree! I was just offering another technique that is helpful to know about in some cases. I also draw complex shapes using a single splinegon object, and making small adjustments using right-click->edit-path, but you can't make true circular arcs that way.